# Web to Desktop application

Tags: web-applications, webbrowser-control, desktop-application

I have a webapplication using only HTML and Javascript (no server interaction). At this point I want to make it available as a desktop application.

Is there a way to deploy a browser (Firefox, Chrome, ...) with my webapplication. It would be great, if I could remove the address-bar and everything, that reminds the user to use a standard webbrowser.

I could even consider writing a simple native application, that just embeds the browser and open the local webapplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET you can use WebBrowser control

```
 public Form1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
     browser.Url = new Uri(@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885639/web-to-desktop-application");
     this.Controls.Add(browser);
 }
```